# Use-State hook passing props down to child

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

Hi guys I'm pretty new to typescript. I'm having trouble passing down `usestate()` props to my child element.

This is the error message I am receiving:
[image]

I think I may have got the typing/interface wrong for passing down `shoppingList` and `setShoppingList()`.

[Here is a codesandbox reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-diffie-ogdk0).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it's my understanding that `shoppingList` should contain an array of strings?

Comment: @KiprasT yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look what type `React.useState()` returns.

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

As you can see the setter has the type `Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>`

If you go further down you see

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

So your setter must be a function type, that receives one parameter and returns void.

Now let's have a look into `SetStateAction<A>`

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

It's either a simple value, or a function that receives the previous state and returns a new one.

So how to fix your types?

```
const Recipe = (props: {
  recipe: Irecipe;
  shoppingList: string[];
  setShoppingList: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>;
}) => {...}
```

or, if you don't plan to use the `prevState` feature anyway you can simplify the type:

```
const Recipe = (props: {
  recipe: Irecipe;
  shoppingList: string[];
  setShoppingList: (value: string[]) => void;
}) => {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: My answer is extremely case specific. @hendra answer is much more complete and should be relied on.**

In types.ts:

```
export type shoppingList = string[];
export type setShoppingList = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>>;
```

In Recipe.tsx:

```
import { Irecipe, shoppingList, setShoppingList } from "../types";

const Recipe = (props: {
  recipe: Irecipe;
  shoppingList: shoppingList;
  setShoppingList: setShoppingList;
}) => {...
```

In App.tsx:

```
import { Irecipe, shoppingList as shoppingListType } from "./types";
...
const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState<shoppingListType>([]);
...
<Recipe
  key={recipe.recipe.url}
  recipe={recipe}
  shoppingList={shoppingList}
  setShoppingList={setShoppingList}
/>
```

Comment: thank you! this worked, I had a hunch I needed to split up my types as they seem conflicting.

Comment: For future reference you should read @hendra's answer, it is much more informative.

Comment: yeah I did I'm grateful @hendra took the time to explain it to me :D